# Automatically re-sizing the JavaFX 2 HTMLEditor control

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to make an editable control using the HTMLEditor ( I'd like a rich-text pane like Swing's JEditorPane or JTextPane but it seems I need to wait a couple of years for that ).  I want to have the user type in text and the control grows to suit.  I have tried catching an event when the scroll-bar appears and increasing the size until it disappears but I can't work out how to wait until the JavaFX thread has actually re-sized the control on its parent.

There's probably a better way to do it than that... any ideas?  Any ideas how to reduce it if text is removed?

TIA Mike Watts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the edit control, use a WebView with [contenteditable set to true](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) like this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685395/webview-with-contenteditable-cannot-be-focused-programmatically) or a [customized HTMLEditor](https://gist.github.com/2514709).

Interact with it using the [Java/JavaScript bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) similar to this [editor](http://jewelsea.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/codemirror-based-code-editor-for-javafx/).  You can [script the WebView using JQuery](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10444280). Run a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) which polls the edit control's text dimensions using a [JQuery dimension query script](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) and [adjust the control size appropriately](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setPrefSize(double,%20double)).

Comment: Thanks for that - yes I had considered that as an option but as you probably appreciate it is rather tortuous ( creating JavaScript written from Java which, if using JQuery, needs to link to an external library ) and therefore time-consuming to test and difficult to implement smoothly.  I was hoping to code it in good ol' Java...

Comment: I've set this as the accepted answer 'cos it does seem to be the only sensible so thanks again for the answer.  Problem ( as I suspected ) is trying to link to JQuery - I've opened another question for that!

Answer (score 0):

[side note: I've added this as an answer even though it is just the details from jewelsea's - I couldn't format the code when replying as a comment].

This is what has worked to a certain extent:

in the html of the WebView component, added a tag `<div id='measured'>` around all of the text blocks

added a handler to the WebView using `setOnKeyPressed` and that calls `checkHeight()`

```
private int lastOffsetHeight;


private void checkHeight() {
    int newHeight = (Integer)webview.getEngine().executeScript(
            "document.getElementById(\"measured\").offsetHeight;") + 14;

    if (newHeight != lastOffsetHeight) {
        lastOffsetHeight = newHeight;
         webview.setPrefHeight(newHeight);
    }
}
```

This is not too bad, main problem is that if all of the text is deleted then the WebView component deletes the div.  As jewelsea mentioned, JQuery might be a better solution but I'll update this if I ever fix the problem of including the library ;-)

Comment: Tried this using jQuery's height() function: doesn't work as well as that shown above ( operation is a bit unpredictable form first glance ).  What's more it's a pain to get the jQuery in there: I ended up putting the jquery.js in the [java] sources directory; using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("jquery.js")` to read the file into a string, then when setting the html on the webiew, wrote that string in as the script ( instead of using the `src` attribute ).