# Highlight text in HTMLEditor JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Hello i'm trying to make a search system and it works like this:

1. You press ctrl + f
2. A text dialogue shows up
3. The text in the text dialogue you entered will highlight in the HTMLEditor

So i'm having problems with the third step I can't find any method about highlighting or find anything on google for HTMLEditor.

So my question is, is it possible to highlight text in a HTMLEditor and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Possible Approach*

There is a similar question for search & highlight functionality in `WebView`:

- [JavaFx | Search and Highlight text | Add Search Bar for loaded web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418626/javafx-search-and-highlight-text-add-search-bar-for-loaded-web-page).

Perhaps you could use an adjustment of that approach (internally the HTMLEditor is implemented as a WebView I believe, though I could be wrong).

You might be able to use some [techniques for customizing the existing HTMLEditor](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2514709) to get UI controls for executing searches into the toolbar of the HTMLEditor.

*Alternatives*

Rather than using `HTMLEditor` you could either use:

- A [`WebView` with ContentEditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685395/webview-with-contenteditable-cannot-be-focused-programmatically).
- A [native JavaFX rich text editor](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).
- A markdown editor (there are native JavaFX solutions for this if you google JavaFX markdown).
- A WebView running an embedded third party JavaScript based HTMLEditor which includes search and replace functionality (there are many of these, you can just run a google search to evaluate alternatives).

If it were me, I'd probably choose the Markdown editor approach if the editor was for a semi-technical audience or the third party JavaScript editor in WebView if the audience was non-technical and required a WYSIWYG HTML editor with a ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using reflection, it can be done natively in Java code.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350328/8837882.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment.